# How to omit raster NA values in corLocal function

Tags: r, raster, terra

I'm calculating local correlation coefficient using the 'corLocal' function from the raster package and pairwise spearman's method.

One of my rasters (**r1**) has NA values while the other (**r2**) does not. I'd expect the function to return a resulting raster with NA values for the same cells as in **r1**. It turns out that my resulting raster is empty -- it has Min and Max values as NA.

How can I solve this? I've tried setting na.rm = TRUE in the function with no success.

Comment: When asking an R question, please include a *minimal,, self-contained, reproducible example*. That is, include some data generated with R code (see `?corLocal`). Also, it is better to use `terra::focalPairs` instead of `raster::corLocal`

Comment: Thanks, Robert! Is there a built-in function for spearman correlation in terra::focalPairs? I'll modify the question to include a reproducible example as well